# Where in the Torah does it says we cannot eat live anmals?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, animals, translation, meat, blood

I remember something along not eating meat with blood still in it. Does it really mean that we cannot eat an animal when it's still alive or that blood is literally not okay?

Some too related follow up:

If it means that we can't eat living animals, can we eat cooked blood (a popular dishes in Indonesia).

Also, when eating meat, it's impossible to completely eliminate blood from the meat right. How do you deal with it?

> But you must not eat meat that has its lifeblood still in it.

http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+9%3A3-4&version=NIV

Does lifeblood here means life or blood? Indonesian translation translate that as simply blood I think followed with a strange theory that life is in the blood.

Indonesian translation:

> Satu-satunya yang tidak boleh kamu makan ialah daging yang masih ada
>   darahnya, sebab nyawa itu ada di dalam darah.

Re-translated to English:

The only thing you cannot eat is meat that still has blood in it. That's because the soul is in the blood.

Other english translation:

> Only, you shall not eat flesh with its life, that is, its blood.

http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+9%3A4&version=NRSV

Which suggest that Indonesian translation is not that far off.

Also:

http://bible.cc/deuteronomy/12-23.htm suggest that it could be the same "Genesis" law that mimic the indonesian translation. Don't eat blood, followed by a theory that life is in the blood.

Comment: Are you referring to Jews or non Jews? The dietary laws may vary.

Comment: I think the non blood thingy comes from noachide that (according to jews) apply to both. I won't give up my pork though I like goats more.

Comment: You seem to be conflating eating bloody meat with eating a live animal. Why? Not every live animal has blood (think jellyfish), and certainly not all bloody meat is that of a live animal. This question as it stands is very unclear to me; the only reason I'm not closing it as "not a real question: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague" (a standard closure reason) is that it has an answer and a comment from two different site regulars who apparently understood the question, so maybe I'm alone in thinking it's "not a real question".

Comment: @msh210, this is not a real question, as it is very confusing in its wording. Having said that, however, cleaning it up doesn't necessarily mean splitting up the two questions. He is clearly misunderstanding the prohibitions and thinking they overlap or are the same. Shimon BM's answer kind of clears it up, though it could use some cleanup of its own.

Comment: Actually. Yea I think there is only one commandment. Actually if you can show that there are 2 that'll be great.

Comment: Ah I remember the verse now. “But you must not eat meat that has its lifeblood still in it." Does that mean life or blood? thanks to one answer.

Comment: In Indonesia, the saying is you can't eat blood followed by a strange theory that life is in the blood.

Comment: @msh210 I can assure you that if I am confused, most people should be. I am not as smart as you, but way above average than most people.

Comment: Updated with more verses based on the one answer. Yes I honestly think the prohibition is the same @SethJ. The wording is similar.

Comment: @JimThio, whatever they do in Indonesia, Judaism regards the laws of the Torah as binding only on Jews; non-Jews, as descendants of Noah, do have certain responsibilities and restrictions.  The vast majority of the laws in the Torah, however, don't apply to non-Jews.

Comment: @JimThio, having said that, one of the laws that Noahides (ie., all mankind) must follow, is the prohibition against eating flesh of an animal that was taken while the animal was still alive. This is a separate prohibition from the law against consuming blood, which, if I'm not mistaken, only applies to Jews. The concept seems on the surface to be related, and I'm not surprised to hear that some people assume they are related, but even if they are, they are not the same prohibition.

Comment: And, yes, "lifeblood" is a good translation. Halachah defines lifeblood as that which comes out of the animal as it is dying. The remaining blood in the meat is divided into categories that range from allowed to prohibited, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: But I still think the question doesn't work. In the first place, the title is asking a different question from what the body talks about. In the second place, the body barely has a question at all. If the question you mean to ask is in the second sentence, what's with all the quotations and talk about Indonesian tradition?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8015/discussion-between-seth-j-and-jim-thio)

Comment: Ah. So life blood here does not mean physical blood. That's why you think (probably correctly) that it's a different commands.

Comment: @JimThio This question is really several questions. Everything from _"Also, when eating meat"_ should be removed. If you want to ask a separate question on the permissibility of eating blood, you can do that. Even then, I would highly recommend you leave out those extraneous translations and just ask what Jews understand the verse to mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're conflating more than one prohibition.

There is one set of prohibitions on consuming the blood of land animals and birds (eg: Leviticus 7:26-27, 17:10-12; Deuteronomy 12:23). This is never permissible, whether or not the animal has died first.

There is a separate prohibition of consuming pieces of land animals or birds that were removed from them while they were alive (Genesis 9:3-4). This is referred to as the prohibition of אבר מן החי (*ever min hachay*, "limb from a live animal"), and is accounted one of the mitzvot given to all of the descendents of Noah (ie: the entire world).

Comment: So only jews aren't allowed to eat blood. The rest of the jews are fine. However, no people should eat limbs from a live anmial?

Comment: There are other reasons as well as to why live animals should not be consumed, such as the prohibition (derived by the rabbis but treated as biblical) of causing suffering to living animals. But yes, the prohibition against consuming blood only pertains to Jews. That said, it is unlike certain other prohibitions (such as abstaining from "labour" on Shabbat), in that non-Jews can also choose to observe it if they wish.

Comment: Shimon bM, you might be interested in the New Testament source (I'm not saying it's authoritative!, but historically interesting) of Acts 15 where non-Jewish Christians are told they don't need to keep all the mitzvot but only "to abstain from food polluted by idols, from sexual immorality, from the meat of strangled animals and from blood."

Comment: By the way, the idea of gentiles not eating a limb from a live animal is interesting since we aren't only allowed to eat kosher meat. I'm not eating meat at all for other reasons, but if I were I would be confused about this issue when in a supermarket... interesting that even though people have mentioned the '7 Laws of Noach' to me I've never been told specifically to be careful about meat where there may be a question, or not. You know, I don't believe you can simply trust the current system... and even less so with imported meat products from some places. What do you think?